# OpenGL (using SOIL) always loads the same image

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

When I load an image, the next image loaded for something else is the same image.

Basically:

I'm making a Pong replica and there is a texture for the paddle and for the ball (yes I have made sure that they are both different). [You can find the source code here.](https://github.com/Bumrang/PongGL) The paddle loads an image fine, but when it comes to the ball it loads the same exact image as the paddle (Paddle = Paddle.cpp , Ball = Ball.cpp).

What could possibly be wrong with it? Am I using SOIL incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From source:
`glBindTexture(PadImg , GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

This is way wrong, it should be 
`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, PadImg);`

You should get familiar with glGetError, it will help you find problems like this.

Also, these calls are in the wrong order:

```
glVertex2f(-w,-10);
glTexCoord2f(0,0);
```

glVertex should always be the last function called per vertex (normals and texcoords come first).